# Get position of selected edges of each mesh island

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need some help with a geometry nodes setup i'm trying to archive. For example i have a grid which is separated in different islands. I selected couple of edges and now i want to retrieve a position vector of the selected edges for each mesh island.

I tried to dynamically input the vertex group selection multiplied by the current mesh island into the attribute statistics node but unfortunately it doesn't work. Maybe someone can help me. I the end i want to distribute points on the faces and all the instances should be aligned so the selected edges of each mesh island.

thanks in advance :)

[image: Node Setup]
[image: Geo]

Comment: sometimes you selected more than one edge per island. Also the sharpness can not be read in some versions of Blender (I think they can only be read in B4.x?)

Comment: i added sharpness only for visualisation. The sedge selection would be inputed as vertex group

Comment: Keep in mind selecting edges via a vertex group is tricky: for example how do you select two edges of a triangle?

Comment: i wont have any triangles. Quads and more. And it will be one edge per face island if it has to be

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work. Altough it seems like a cheating solution and i'm wondering if there isn't a smarter way. @Markus von Broady I did the same procedure like you suggested in my other post with the lots and houses.

I separated my edges from the rest of the geo, offsetted them with the mesh island index in z direction. The same thing i did with the points and then used geometry proximty to find the closest edge position to calculate my orientation. By offsetting per mesh island i'm preventing that edges from other mesh islands are closer to my instance point.

[image: result]
[image: nodetree]

[image]